# How to pull/run container when build is finished?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-container-builder

I am using Google Container Builder to build images and push them to gcr.io

How can trigger a pull/run on a CoreOS VM after the build is finished? 
(I can't use Google Container Engine)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building the container in the Cloud Shell, and need to pull and run the image on your CoreOS VM, you could use the following command as a basis to achieve this. This presumes you are using a config file to instruct Container Builder to perform tasks based on your specifications, and that you are in the same directory as the Dockerfile (a similar method to that outlined [here](https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/quickstart-docker#build_using_a_build_config_file)):

`gcloud container builds submit --config cloudbuild.yaml . && gcloud compute ssh INSTANCE_NAME -- 'docker run -d gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/IMAGE:TAG'`

The above command utilizes Container Builder to build the image and push it to Container Registry. Once that command completes the build and push, it accesses the instance and executes a `docker run` command to automatically run the image that is now stored in Container Registry. The command automatically exits the remote instance once complete.